# Splitting fraction numerators in mathjax?

Tags: fractions, split, mathjax

In standard latex, `\splitfrac` can be used to split a large numerator across two lines, and you can nest `splitfrac` to break up a numerator into three or more lines.  But mathjax doesn't seem to support `\splitfrac`: so what is the best method of splitting up a long numerator?

Comment: Well, it is off topic here.

Comment: As JouleV mentions, mathjax is off topic here. It is not latex under the hood, it us a javascript library that know how (in a browser) render a subset of latex' math syntax. As such we have no involvement in what is and is not supported within mathjax.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up - the moderators can remove my post and I'll ask elsewhere, as recommended.